# Can a signed apk be extracted and edited?

Tags: android, android-studio

What I want to know is can a signed apk be extracted and edited? And can the attacker again compress the apk and attack a victim?

I know that we can use proguard to obscure the code but some people said that the apk still can be extracted and modified through reverse engineering.

My main concern is I want to encrypt my java files because I have some authentication data in my java files.

Can anyone give me a bulletproof method to protect java files from being inaccessible.

Edit -

Found few old thread in stack but they never explained about signed apk and protect them from getting exploited.

Comment: I don't really know about signed apk but 7zip always does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Cryptographic signing is not encryption.  Signing proves that whoever signed it knew a secret key.  Assuming the key is kept secure, you can be sure that two files signed by the same key are from the same person.  With some forms of signing with public and private keys, it can be used to prove the identity of the signer.  This does not provide any protection against reading that data, although it does provide protection against a counterfeit copy of the app being claimed as the real thing (assuming the user pays attention to the signature).

There is no way to do what you want to do.  In the end, an app has to be run by a processor or interpreter.  That means it needs to be translated into instructions that the processor understands.  If you want something to be secure, do not put it on a client device.  There is no way to protect it if you're sending it to a device that needs to decrypt it and use it.

Comment: Is there any way to to make it hard to reverse engineering the apk? I just don't want human to read my files.

Comment: A variety of ways, but the real question is-  why do you care?  If your algorithm is truly innovative, apply for a patent.  You'll get real protection from that.  If its data you're worried about, protect it by not moving it off the server.  If you're worried about the code just because you worry about copying, realize that copying most apps is trivial-  a senior dev with experience could rewrite almost any app with a little bit of research.  What keeps you safe is continuing to innovate and willingness to do the work, as well as the business built around your app.

Comment: Wow such a good explanation. Thanks for explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any APK can be decompressed and have its sources read. You cannot, however, edit it and sign it without the signing key.

There is no way to encrypt your source files and everything inside of them is readable by anyone. Authentication data shouldn't be stored in an application if it is expected to be secret.

Answer (score 0):

signed apks can easily be reverse engineered. You should never place authentication data in the source code. There is no bullet proof solution for this. However you can make it difficult for the attacker by encoding and not placing your critical data in obvious places.

Comment: Can I encrypt only the authentication file? And remaining file normal?

Comment: You cannot encrypt java file. You can encrypt text files, but you need to keep the decryption key inside the app. so that is not a solution. Only possible solution is to perform the authentication from a back end server.

Comment: Yup I understood that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another way to use your authentication data, I've read something about building a binary and storing inside the lib directory as a .so file, I'm not sure how exactly it's the proccess because I didn't tried, but you can research another methods, storing private data on Java source it's not secure.